# Помогите новичку в php, отфильтровать массив

Tags: php

Всем доброго времени суток. Помогите новичку в php, отфильтровать массив.
В скрипте php через запрос curl получаю данные в переменную $date.
Пример данных в переменной $date:

```
tdClass Object
(
    [Entities] => stdClass Object
        (
            [BackupTaskSessions] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [BackupTaskSessions] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [CreationTimeUTC] => 2020-09-07T16:05:44Z
                                    [EndTimeUTC] => 2020-09-07T16:06:23Z
                                    [State] => Completed
                                    [Result] => Success
                                    [TotalSize] => 32212254720
                                    [VmDisplayName] => nonono.local
                                    [Name] => nonono.local@2020-09-07 16:05:44
                                )  
                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [CreationTimeUTC] => 2020-10-31T16:41:39Z
                                    [EndTimeUTC] => 2020-10-31T16:42:20Z
                                    [State] => Completed
                                    [Result] => Success
                                    [TotalSize] => 32282254420
                                    [VmDisplayName] => hohohohoho.local
                                    [Name] => hohohohoho.local@2020-10-31 16:41:39
                                )  
                           [2] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [CreationTimeUTC] => 2020-10-31T17:41:39Z
                                    [EndTimeUTC] => 2020-18-31T17:42:20Z
                                    [State] => Completed
                                    [Result] => Success
                                    [TotalSize] => 32412294720
                                    [VmDisplayName] => hahahahaha.local
                                    [Name] => hahahahaha.local@2020-10-31 17:41:39
                                )
                           [3] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [CreationTimeUTC] => 2020-09-07T17:05:44Z
                                    [EndTimeUTC] => 2020-09-07T17:06:23Z
                                    [State] => Completed
                                    [Result] => Success
                                    [TotalSize] => 32212754820
                                    [VmDisplayName] => nanana.local
                                    [Name] => nanana.local@2020-09-07 17:05:44
                                )  
                                и т.д.                          
                       )

                )

        )
)
```

Необходимо отфильтровать Array по вчерашней дате ключа CreationTimeUTC.
Дату задаю так

```
$cdate = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", strtotime("-1 day"));
```

Для понимания чего хочу добиться в результате если `$cdate = 2020-10-31T00:00:00Z`
Результат:

```
tdClass Object
    (
        [Entities] => stdClass Object
            (
                [BackupTaskSessions] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [BackupTaskSessions] => Array
                            (
                                [1] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [CreationTimeUTC] => 2020-10-31T16:41:39Z
                                        [EndTimeUTC] => 2020-10-31T16:42:20Z
                                        [State] => Completed
                                        [Result] => Success
                                        [TotalSize] => 32282254420
                                        [VmDisplayName] => hohohohoho.local
                                        [Name] => hohohohoho.local@2020-10-31 16:41:39
                                    )  
                               [2] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [CreationTimeUTC] => 2020-10-31T17:41:39Z
                                        [EndTimeUTC] => 2020-18-31T17:42:20Z
                                        [State] => Completed
                                        [Result] => Success
                                        [TotalSize] => 32412294720
                                        [VmDisplayName] => hahahahaha.local
                                        [Name] => hahahahaha.local@2020-10-31 17:41:39
                                    )
                                    и т.д.                          
                           )
    
                    )
    
            )
    )
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: если по дате надо, то отсекайте вообще время и сравнивайте только дату.

Comment: Используйте usort вкупе с [createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.createfromformat.php). Парсите даты в объекты DateTime, и можете делать их прямое сравнение друг с другом на больше/меньше для сортировки. Примеры пользовательской сортировки есть по ссылке.

Answer (score 0):

```
const DATETIME_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z';

$array = [];

$object1 = new stdClass();
$object1->CreationTimeUTC = '2020-11-01T16:41:39Z';
$array[] = $object1;

$object2 = new stdClass();
$object2->CreationTimeUTC = '2020-10-29T12:01:23Z';
$array[] = $object2;

$object3 = new stdClass();
$object3->CreationTimeUTC = '2020-11-01T19:21:44Z';
$array[] = $object3;

$yesterday = (new DateTime)->modify('-1 day');

// Отбросим объекты, у которых дата не равна вчерашней
$array = array_filter($array, function (stdClass $object) use ($yesterday): bool {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat(DATETIME_FORMAT, $object->CreationTimeUTC);

    return $yesterday->format('Y-m-d') === $date->format('Y-m-d');
});
// Затем, сортируем объекты по возрастанию времени
usort($array, function (stdClass $a, stdClass $b): int {
    $dateA = DateTime::createFromFormat(DATETIME_FORMAT, $a->CreationTimeUTC);
    $dateB = DateTime::createFromFormat(DATETIME_FORMAT, $b->CreationTimeUTC);

    return $dateA <=> $dateB;
});
// В массиве остались объекты 1 и 3
```

Вам только остаётся добраться до массива с датами, путь будет примерно такой: `$stdObject->Entities->BackupTaskSessions->BackupTaskSessions;`